# How to move 1 WP site from a mult-site environment to a different multi-site area

Tags: multisite, plugin-recommendation, migration, site-url

How to move 1 WP site from a mult-site environment to a different multi-site area?

Doing on same server if that assists at all.

We know how to move a site from a multi-site area into a single site area, and vice versa. Loads of coverage and instructions on this. But not to move a site from 1 multi-site WP area to another on different domain/server.

Answer (score 2):

If you know how WordPress is structured internally it should not be too hard. Here are the steps:

1. For your site to migrate create a new site in the WordPress multisite environment (the information in the following tables must fit the new environment)

> ```
> wp_blogs (especially this)
> wp_blogs_versions (probably irrelevant)
> wp_registration_log (probably irrelevant)
> wp_signups (probably irrelevant)
> wp_site (especially this)
> wp_sitemeta (especially this)
> ```

3. Extract the media folder from the old multisite subsite and copy it to the new multisite subsite
4. The following tables are site specific - move them from the old subsite to the new subsite (delete the tables from the new multisite and replace them, adjust the prefix)

> ```
> wp_2_commentmeta
> wp_2_comments
> wp_2_links
> wp_2_options
> wp_2_postmeta
> wp_2_posts
> wp_2_terms
> wp_2_termmeta
> wp_2_term_relationships
> wp_2_term_taxonomy
> ```

4. The `wp_users` and `wp_usermeta` information will be different in your new multisite environment - you will have to extract the information from the old database or synchronize them somehow
5. The Plugins/Themes in your new environment will be different, you have to make sure that this is either available or you remove those functionality from the subsite first.

Note that there might still be certain problems to fix as of different environments.

An easier way is to just copy over the theme and export the users and their contents and import them in your new site. If this is sufficient depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yep, I thought about doing manually. Have done before manually for single site to single site, but was feeling a little lazier I guess, and looking for plugin out there to do in "single click", but doesn't seem to exist at the moment. Even for a paid plugin. Will use your answer as a guide and might re-post another answer with exact process used and order of events. May be quicker using inherent WordPress Import/Export function as you say and move files. Then I think Media from FTP plugin needs used to attached images to database etc.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood the question correctly, you want to move a multisite sub-site from one site to another multisite subsite in different domain or server?

There is a plugin that can do this easily: https://wordpress.org/plugins/prime-mover/

Documentation: 
https://codexonics.com/prime_mover/prime-mover/how-to-migrate-your-wordpress-multisite-sub-site-to-another-multisite-sub-site/

https://codexonics.com/prime_mover/prime-mover/important-notes-on-prime-mover-single-site-and-multisite-packages/

The plugin can also do: single-site to single-site, single-site to multisite, multisite to single-site and multisite subsite to another multisite subsite migrations (just like your case). Just activate on the network admin go to the sub-site listed in Network Sites and click Export to generate site package. On the target end.

One thing that is important is that in WordPress multisite, subsite is identified by blog ID. So it means that if in the origin multisite, the subsite has a blog ID of 7. It needs to be migrated also on the target server with a blog ID of 7.

Otherwise if its different blog ID, it could mean different site. So cannot mix it up.

Ideally in multisite to multisite migration, domain name / website URL can change. But not its blog ID, which is supposed to be used as a means of identification.